# HTTPS to HTTPS redirect Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

How can I redirect an HTTPS to another HTTPS (I only got one SSL certificate for a single domain)?

For example, how to redirect from `https://example.org` to `https://example.com`?

I already tried to search Google and other forums, but nothing I found worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format your URL's. Since they are not actual links, they can be formatted as inline code so that they are rendered properly. Please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Also, be sure that you use at least two relevant tags if possible. Last but not least, I would strongly recommend you to include in the question what you have already tried. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is super easy to do:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  example.org;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

See [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html), it describes a difference between rewrite and 301 redirect (recommended since Nginx 0.9.1)

UPDATE:

```
http {
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/10599/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/10599/server.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem;


    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  example.eu www.example.eu example.org www.example.org www.example.com;
        return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }


    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        root /home/forge/example.com;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        client_max_body_size 20m;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        access_log off;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

        error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  example.org;
    return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}` When I add this, nginx stops working. I already have 1 SSL domain in my configuration.

Comment: you can add as much server blocks as you need, Nginx stopped working by a different reason. We don't know until you can share error log with us.

Comment: I get the following: `error: 2015/09/07 12:44:27 [error] 6848#0: *11 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: IP_ADDRESS_HERE, server: 0.0.0.0:443`

Comment: simply move *ssl_* directives up to **http** block

Comment: it's already on the first line, but no ssl certificate is installed on the domain, I just want to simply redirect to a domain who does have an SSL certificate.

Comment: A better solution than moving the ssl directives to the http block (because that cannot be done within site-specific conf files) is to set `default_server` so that you have `listen 443 ssl default_server;` in the last server block.

Answer (score 0):

**Below code is worked properly for me.**

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

'rewrite' forcefully update redirect rule.

**Steps:**

```
1.Add above code in ngnix filename.conf below the server name
2.sudo service ngnix restart
3.Remove rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
4.sudo service ngnix restart
```

**Example**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;

  root /home/ubuntu/example/dist;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

  location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3012/;
  }

  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example/certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example/private.key;
}
```